# when there is loop in the background's function, multisession not work?

Tags: r

I want to run fetch data repeatedly, so in the background process there is dead loop.

My code is as follows:

```
library(future)
plan("multisession")

test_function <- function()
{
  while(TRUE)
  {
    print("aaaa")
    Sys.sleep(1);
  }
  print("bbb")
  return(0)
}

f <- future({
  test_function()
})
y <- value(f)
```

When running the code, no output.

When comment the while loop, the output "bbbb" shows. Why?

I have updated for adding logs, still no output.

```
library(future)
library(logger)
plan("multisession")

test_function <- function()
{
  while(TRUE)
  {
  t_log_path = tempfile()
    dir.create(t_log_path,recursive = TRUE)
    t_a = file.path(t_log_path,'import_data_log')
    log_appender(appender_tee(t_a, max_lines = 10))
    t_logger_layout <- layout_glue_generator(format = '{level} [{time}] {node}/{pid}/{namespace}/{fn}  {msg}')
    log_layout(t_logger_layout)
    log_info("log here")
    print("aaaa")
    Sys.sleep(1);
  }
  print("bbb")
  return(0)
}

# test_function()
f <- future({
  test_function()
})
y <- value(f)
```

Comment: I have used logs before, and no response. For simplifying the problem, the log and other  code lines have been removed together.

Comment: I have added a  new version with log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your future is never resolved

From the `future` [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html):

> A future is an abstraction for a value that may be available at some point in the future. The state of a future can either be unresolved or resolved. As soon as it is resolved, the value is available instantaneously. If the value is queried while the future is still unresolved, the current process is blocked until the future is resolved.

The main thing going on in your code is that your `while(TRUE)` loop  has no `break` clause, meaning it never exits. Anything after this loop is never evaluated. This means that `test_function()` is never resolved, so you never get any output. Compare that to this:

```r
library(future)
plan(multisession)

test_function <- function(i = 1) {
    while (i <= 5) {
        cat(i, append = TRUE)
        i <- i + 1
    }
    cat("\nEnd of loop\n")
    return(0)
}
f <- future(test_function())
x <- value(f) # This prints the output below (and sets x to 0)
# 12345
# End of loop
```

This resolves after 5 iterations, so we see the output printed when we query the future by running `value(f)`. Conversely, if we replace `while(i <=5)` with `while(TRUE)`, then `x <- value(f)` will block your R terminal. The future is never resolved so we never see any output.

#### Working with unresolved futures

If you want to loop forever, the key is never to try to resolve your future. For example to write to a log file every second you can do:

```r
test_function <- function() {
    repeat  {
        # This will write to ./logfile.txt
        write(
            sprintf("Logging at: %s", Sys.time()), "./logfile.txt",
            append = TRUE
        )
        Sys.sleep(1)
    }
    # The function will never return so anything
    # here is irrelevant
    return(0)
}
f <- future(test_function())
```

If you open `"./logfile.txt"`, you will see a new line being appended every second. However, do not run `value(f)`. This will block your R terminal as the function never returns. If you then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to get your terminal back, the function stops running.

The key point is that the output is only printed to the console at the point the future is resolved. If it is never resolved, you will never get the output. However, operations with side-effects will happen while the future is unresolved, such as API calls or writing to files. If you wish to do such an operation in a loop with no break point, never try to resolve the future with `value()`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is very helpful.